# Analytic solution to sensor fusion problem

Tags: self-learning, signal-processing, bayesian, estimation, kalman-filter

I came across this [blog-post describing an Iterative Least Squares approach](https://nbviewer.org/github/rlabbe/Kalman-and-Bayesian-Filters-in-Python/blob/master/Supporting_Notebooks/Iterative-Least-Squares-for-Sensor-Fusion.ipynb) for solving a sensor fusion problem. I'm confused why there is a need for an iterative approximation, when I think it can be solved analytically? I am an outsider to this field, so I am hoping someone can point out where I may be misunderstanding.

[image]

- The problem is motivated by describing 4 satellites that sense an object's coordinates (illustrated above for 2-D, but abstracted as a 3-D problem).
- The position of the object, sensed by each satellite, is modeled after a multivariate Gaussian distribution $p_{i}(x, y, z) =\left(b^3 / \pi^{3 / 2}\right) \exp \left(-b^2 ((x-x_{i})^{2}+(y-y_{i})^{2}+(z-z_{i}^{2}\right))$ where $(x_{i}, y_{i}, z_{i})$ is the satellite's position.
- This blog goes on to motivate that because the system is **overdetermined** there is a need to approximate to recover the most likely position $(x, y, z)$ of the sensed object.

What I'm confused about is, if each satellite models the object's position after a Gaussian, **isn't the most likely position of the object the MLE of the product of $n$ multivariate Gaussian PDFs, for $n =$ number of sensors**? This also happens to the **mean** of $N$ multivariate Gaussian PDFs, is this not?

If this is the case, why is there a need to iteratively approximate $(x, y, z)$ when one can find the MLE of $$p_{1}(x, y, z) p_{2}(x, y, z) p_{3}(x, y, z) p_{4}(x, y, z)$$ where $$p_{i}(x, y, z) =\left(b^3 / \pi^{3 / 2}\right) \exp \left(-b^2 ((x-x_{i})^{2}+(y-y_{i})^{2}+(z-z_{i})^{2})\right)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of your confusion is that the model of the object's position per satellite is not a multivariate Gaussian. It is a shell around the satellite at a radius $R_i$ determined by the time delay, as can be seen in the image. This shell has an uncertainty which may be modeled by a Gaussian around the radius $R_i$.